# Influxdb authentication does not work in Windows

Tags: windows, authentication, influxdb

I downloaded InfluxDB v1.7.10 in Windows.
I edited influxdb.conf to enable **http** and **auth**

```
[http]
  # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = true

  # Determines whether the Flux query endpoint is enabled.
  # flux-enabled = false

  # Determines whether the Flux query logging is enabled.
  # flux-log-enabled = false

  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
   bind-address = ":8086"

  # Determines whether user authentication is enabled over HTTP/HTTPS.
   auth-enabled = true
```

After started influxd.exe, the service started successfully. 
However, the authentication does not work because I still can query the Infos from influxDB without any user tokens (i.e., username and password).
And we can observe the log still tells the auth is not enabled:

```
2020-02-14T09:53:22.371821Z     info    Starting HTTP service   {"log_id": "0KxmiPwl000", "service": "httpd", "authentication": false}
```

I also installed influxDB v1.7.10 in Ubuntu18.04, and everything goes fine after I enabled the authentication as the steps above.

I don't know where something goes wrong but the program does not seem to read from influxdb.conf in Windows at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had trouble getting InfluxDB to use the config file. 
It works for me when I add the config file as an argument.
I run InfluxDB as a service to do that, I use nssm for that:

1. Install nssm (or another suitable tool)
2. Create a new service
3. Provide the path to influxdb.exe
4. Add this argument (alter path accordingly) to the service: `config "C:\path\to\your\influxdb\config"`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're right in that your customized influxdb.conf is ignored. To quickly test if that is indeed the reason why authentication doesn't work, use the config flag when running influxd.exe from your command prompt like so:

```
influxd.exe -config <path to your custom influxdb.conf>
```

Be warned, though, that this will, for whatever reason, turn influxd.exe into an unkillable process (at least, I wasn't able to figure out how to kill it). In other words, you'll have to reboot your computer to shutdown influxDB when running it like this. Nevertheless, I think it's the easiest way to quickly test whether an ignored config is indeed the reason why your authentication is not working properly.

If authentication works when starting influxd.exe as described above, then I would strongly encourage you to follow [fxweidinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440690/16305167). (Note: In point 3., "Provide the path to influxdb.exe", replace "influxdb.exe" with "influxd.exe".)

Also, you absolutely want to check out this [post](http://www.richardn.ca/2019/01/04/installing-influxdb-on-windows/) by Richard Niemand, especially section 2. (It's basically a very detailed version of [fxweidinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440690/16305167).)